# Confusion with integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As I understand it, an integral domain is a commutative ring with no zero divisors. I have seen examples of finite integral domains, which I will call $D$ (i.e. $J_p$), but how can this be? A simple corollary to Lagrange's Theorem is that for any $d\in D$, $d*\mid D\mid=0$. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what your objection is

Comment: @G.Chiusole Well, if we let $n=\mid D\mid$, and take some $d\neq0,d\in D$, we get that $nd=0$. Does that not make $d$ a zero divisor?

Comment: Think about the meaning of the $n$'th multiple $\,n\cdot x\,$ vs. the ring product $\, y * x\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion is that $|D|$ doesn’t necessarily belong to $D$. For $D$ to be an integral domain any product of two non-zero elements *in* $D$ must be non-zero. For example $\mathbb Z_5$, which is an integral domain whose order is $5$, but $5$ is not contained in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: Is it possible that you mean with 5 is not contained in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ that 5 is $5\cdot 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, which is zero?